# overlapping of bar plots in one graph

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe that has 237 columns and 6 rows:

```
                                   1          2          3          4    ...        234        235        236        237
Hydrophobic                  19.324182   0.422386   2.006336   7.814150  ...  50.791975   3.379092   5.807814   0.000000
Negative                      0.211193   0.000000   0.000000   0.211193  ...   0.422386   0.211193   1.372756   0.105597
Positive                      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.105597  ...   0.527983  43.928194   2.851109   0.422386
Special                      16.050686   0.000000   1.267159   2.534319  ...   0.844773   0.211193   0.105597   0.422386
Polar                        21.858501   0.211193   1.795143   6.019007  ...   0.739176   2.323126  26.082365   0.000000
Gap                          42.449842  99.260824  94.825766  83.210137  ...  46.568110  49.841605  63.674762  98.944034
```

Because I want to plot for each column the percentage of the row types in a stacked way, I transposed the dataframe and plot it:

```
transpose_df=df.transpose()

transpose_df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

However, the plot does not look good, I read the documentation of matplotlib but I could not understand how to do it

[image]

Unfortunatly, I tried to make the graph vertical as was suggested but I got the same result even increasing the width

```
transpose_df.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(5, 50))
```

[image]

Any idea how to avoid the overlap and have a clearer graph.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 237 columns to plot, you can save some space by using the width argument and avoid having blanks between bars. Appart from that, there is no way to make your x ticks labels readable with that many columns.

The best way to plot that many columns is, I think, by using a horizontal bar graph and setting a large height for your plot. It's easier to scroll vertically than horizontally.

Here is an example:

```py
transpose_df.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(5, 30))
```

Comment: I was afraid that the amount of columns could be the major problem. May be I could plot smaller graph of 20 or 50 columns

Comment: I edited my answer by adding a way to plot it vertically

Comment: Unfortunatly I got the same overlap as in the horizontal way. I don't know ifthere is a way to share you this figure in a comment

Comment: Does the figure have the same shape ? You can try to increase 30 to a greater value like 50. To share the plot, you can edit your question :)

Comment: Your graph looks like height and width are inverted, it's the height that should be increased, not the width. Swap 5 and 50 ?

Comment: you are right, much better now. But still an overlap, I think as you say before is because of the amount of columns that I have

Comment: You can always increase the height of your graph until you reach the expected result. Could you update the graph in the question to see what is doable ?